# c++ Mapping class to number

Tags: c++, mapping

I recently started with c++ development. I've come to a problem of which I am not able to solve, given that I am unaware if the following is possible.

> I want to create a mapping between a number and class, which are derived from an abstract class.

Essentially what I would like to be able to do is create a factory method that can create a new instance of a class based on a given number associated with that class.

I know that I could do the following...

```
Vehicle *Vehicle::from_type(byte type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case 0x00: return new Bicyle();
        case 0x01: return new Car();
        ...
        case 0x10: return new Truck();
    }

    return null;
}
```

..., but I'd rather not as I  want to keep it DRY.

It there a way where one can do something along the lines of this:

```
// I know this is incorrect syntax
const map<byte, class extends Vehicle> VEHICLE_MAPPING = {{0x00, Bicyle}, {0x01, Car}, ..., {0x10, Truck}};

Vehicle *Vehicle::from_type(byte type)
{   
    return new VEHICLE_MAPPING[type]();
}
```

Comment: If the first one violated DRY, the second one does too. I'd stick with the first solution

Comment: Your first solution is DRY enough and the second, to my knowledge, impossible. That said you should read about smart pointers, your code looks outdated.

Comment: It seems that you will need a factory class for each of derived class. Next you can set it in your map. I don't know if it is good idea for you. If yes, I can provide some code to answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how your approach could work with usage of `std::map<uint8_t, std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>>`, but there is a problem - you wouldn't be able to initialise that map with `initializer_list`, since it *copies* the elements and, as we all know, `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. You would have to create an `init()` function to initialise the map that would use similar logic to your `Vehicle *Vehicle::from_type(byte type)`, which would simply be pointless given you already have your function.

Furthermore, I disagree that your first solution violates DRY. It is actually correct in a sense that you won't be forced to use `switch` or `if`s elsewhere in the code. I'd definitely stick with it.

The final note - you *could* use `std::map<uint8_t, std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>>` instead of `std::map<uint8_t, std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>>` and initialise it with `initializer_list`, since `std::shared_ptr` *can* be copied, but I wouldn't advise that since it wrongly indicates the usage of `shared_ptr`. If you somehow feel forced to do so, here is an example:

```
class Base{ public: virtual ~Base() = default; };
class Derived1 : public Base{};
class Derived2 : public Base{};

class derived_factory{
    private:
        derived_factory();
        static inline std::map<uint8_t, std::shared_ptr<Base>> base_map = {
            {0x00, std::make_shared<Derived1>()},
            {0x01, std::make_shared<Derived2>()}
        };
    public:
        static std::unique_ptr<Base> from_type(uint8_t type)
        {
            return std::make_unique<Base>(*base_map[type]);
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto ptr = derived_factory::from_type(0x00);
    // ptr is of a type std::unique_ptr<Base> and points to Derived1 object
}
```

Additional note that should be a final discouragement of using this solution is that it's quite slow. It constructs the objects in a map and does nothing with them except for keeping them as 'templated' copy examples.

Comment: This was essentially what I was after. Thank you. However, I've taken in your advice, and others from the comments on my post, and I've chosen to stick with what I initially had before. My knowledge to c++ does not come this far, which made me jump to conclusion in which I oversaw that `option 2` also pretty much 'violates' DRY. I can see how this, or any similar, solution to my question can be very slow. Nevertheless, I've accepted your post as an answer to my question as it does what my initial thoughts were.

Answer (score 1):

If they're all derived from a base class, you can use the factory pattern, e.g., from [Loki's implementation](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Pattern.FactoryMethod) (see *Modern C++ Design* for the details, though that book is pre-C++11).

The following creates some concrete vehicles and puts them in a vector and then calls the `drive()` method on each of them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "factory.h"

struct Vehicle
{
  virtual ~Vehicle() = default;
  virtual void drive() = 0;
};

struct Car : Vehicle
{
  static constexpr auto ID = 1;
  void drive() override { std::cout << "Car\n"; }
};

struct Truck : Vehicle
{
  static constexpr auto ID = 2;
  void drive() override { std::cout << "Truck\n"; }
};

// Create the factory object
auto g_factory = MyUtil::Factory<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>, int>{};

void RegisterTypesWithFactory()
{
    // We pass in creator functions for each type. Note that these
    // could be lambdas or some other freestanding function and they
    // could accept parameters.
    g_factory.Register( Car::ID,   &std::make_unique<Car> );
    g_factory.Register( Truck::ID, &std::make_unique<Truck> );
}

int main()
{
    // Configure the factory
    // Note: Registration can be done any time, e.g., later based on input 
    // from a file. I do them all at once here for convenience of illustration.
    RegisterTypesWithFactory();

    // Create some objects with the factory
    auto vehicles = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>>{};
    vehicles.emplace_back( g_factory.Create( Car::ID ) );
    vehicles.emplace_back( g_factory.Create( Truck::ID ) );

    // Do something with the objects
    for( const auto& v : vehicles )
    {
        v->drive();
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Car
Truck
```

See it run live on <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i032RGQ0x1PvYhpp)</kbd>.